# Does an UNIQUE constraint remove the need for an explicit index in Sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

There are some columns that I wish to create indexes for to improve look-up and sorting speeds. If that column is marked as `UNIQUE`, for instance:

```
CREATE TABLE "foo" (
    "bar" TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
)
```

is the column "bar" now indexed in such a way that this:

```
CREATE INDEX foo_bar ON foo(bar)
```

will provide no speed bonus for searches and sorts?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`UNIQUE` and `PRIMARY KEY` constraints indeed create an internal index to speed up their lookups, so you do not need to create your own.
(see the [documentation](http://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#uniqueconst))

Comment: The note about the "significant overhead" is no longer available on the SQLite page. Probably this means that this is no longer the case and you can create an explicit index without any overhead.

Comment: @riot_starter Well, the overhead has never been larger than that for an explicit index

Comment: If that's the overhead, I think it is negligible, compared to the fact that you can have a more meaningful index name in EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN, than when using the internal one (provided that SQLite will not create a redundant, internal index though)..

Comment: The overhead is the storage space and the I/O needed to update the index when the actual table data changes; this is doubled if you create a duplicate index.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion: what I mean is that if you create an explicit UNIQUE index and omit the UNIQUE constraint from the table, it will be equivalent to adding the constraint and omitting the explicit index. In the first case where will be only one external UNIQUE index and in the later case there will be only one internal UNIQUE index. In this case the overhead is negligible, if any.